# Rectilinear generators of hyperbolic paraboloid.

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadrics

> Given a point on a hyperbolic paraboloid, prove that there exist exactly 2 lines that pass through that point and lie on the surface of that paraboloid.

Basically it's asked to prove that there are exactly 2 rectilinear generators passing through any given point of such paraboloid (it's also necessary to prove their existence). I know that hyperbolic paraboloid is a ruled surface and know the equations of its rectilinear generators passing through a given point, but I have no idea how to prove the claim.

Comment: How is defined a hyperboloid paraboloid for you ? By equation $z=xy$ or $z=x^2-y^2 ?$

Comment: Little orthographic detail : "for it's rectilinear" $\to$ "for its rectilinear"

Comment: @JeanMarie By equation $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 2z$$

Comment: Intersect with the tangent plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=z$$

be the equation of the Hyperbolic Paraboloid (HP in short).

Consider the following family of lines with non zero parameter $c$

$$(L_c) \ \begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{a}-\dfrac{y}{b}&=&c\\
\dfrac{x}{a}+\dfrac{y}{b}&=&\dfrac{z}{c}
\end{cases} \implies \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=z$$

(the implication is obtained by multiplying the equations)

But **implication** means for corresponding sets, **inclusion**. In this way, we have proven that $(L_c) \subset (HP).$

Same reasoning for the other (distinct) family:

$$(L'_d) \ \begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{a}+\dfrac{y}{b}&=&d\\
\dfrac{x}{a}-\dfrac{y}{b}&=&\dfrac{z}{d}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain why the fact that multiplying equations of $(L_c)$ gives us the equation of $(HP)$ implies that $(L_c) \subset (HP)$ ?

Comment: See the modification I just did of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

comment

BTW, The 2 lines are geodesics, unique euclidean straight lines for

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 2z.$$